# VBA Excel paste changes values

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying data from one workbook ("firstWB") to another one ("secondWB"). The first workbook is actually a .txt file. I changed the file extension to .xls to work with it.

In my firstWB I have this column containing ths data:

```
0
0
0
0
0
2,378
2,378
3,038
3,038
3,146
3,146
3,146
3,151
3,151
3,107
3,107
```

Using `firstWB.Sheets(1).Range(copyRng.Address).Copy` I'll put the data into my clipboard. Then I paste it using `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("A2")`. 
Copy and pasting works fine, but the values change. In my SecondWB if find this data:

```
0,000
0,000
0,000
0,000
0,000
2.378
2.378
3.038
3.038
3.146
3.146
3.146
3.151
3.151
3.107
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in firstWB hard data, or is it cell references? I have a feeling that the .copy is copying the cell references, so when you paste, the references then refer to another location with different info.

One possible solution is to set the range values equal to eachother, instead of copy/pasting.  This should give you an idea of how to do that (note you will have to tweak it to fit your ranges):

```
sub test()
dim secondWB as worksheet
dim rng as Range, rng2 as Range 'rng will be the range you want to copy, rng2 is destination

Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
set rng2 = secondWB.range("B1:B10")

rng2.Value = rng.value 'this will set the range values equal.
end sub
```

Comment: it's hard data. Unfortunatly this does not solve my problem. Only difference I see is that I do not have a decimal point separator.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's simply a formatting issue?  Check to see if the format in your secondWB is also something like "number".  It looks like it is switching from US numerical format (with a comma every 3 digits) to European (use decimals every 3).

Comment: Yes it looks like. But how can I check the language?!

Comment: If you try this formula (where A1 is a cell with the European format), does it fix the style? `=TEXT(A1,"#,###,###.##")`

Comment: Instead of simply changing the .txt extension to open in Excel, have you tried putting the data in yourself, and seeing if Excel still gives you trouble? Maybe it's doing something with the formatting in the forced change from .txt to .xlsx.